# .NET healthcheck addcheck or remove dynamicly in controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, health-check

I use this code block for in startup.cs :

```
    var bldr = builder.Services
  .AddHealthChecks();
    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        bldr = bldr.AddCheck(
            url,
          new HealhCheck(url));
    }
```

But i need add more or remove healthchecks in controller or another class. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to add or remove healthchecks in another controller or class?  A healthcheck is used to check an apps status.  If a controller action being executed can change the overall status of the app, then that action should probably change the app's state and an existing healthcheck should look at that state to determine the health of the app.

Comment: A healhtcheck also used to check dependency connections. Based on some situation my dependecies change and i want to check it dynamicly.

Comment: Can you use a health check service?  It would be one route, but then it could do different things based on dependency injection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-6.0#dependency-injection-and-health-checks

Comment: That's not what i exactly want but thank you.